# Definition of a graded vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

I would like to know what the exact definition of a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded (smooth) vector bundle is. There is an obvious answer to this if only finitely many components of a graded vector bundle are nontrivial.

In general I suppose that a graded vector bundle over a smooth manifold $M$ is a graded object in the category of vector bundles over $M$ which you can equivalently think of as just a collection of vector bundles $(E_i)_{i\in \mathbb{Z}}$ over $M$. Maybe you should additionally require that for every $p\in M$ you can find an open neighborhood $U$ such that all ${E_i}_{|U}, i\in \mathbb{Z}$ are trivial.

I´ve also seen authors using the notation $E=\bigoplus_{i\in \mathbb{Z}}E_i$, so maybe you rather want to view a graded vector bundle as a bundle of graded vector spaces with fibers $\bigoplus_{i\in \mathbb{Z}}{E_i}_p,\:p\in M$?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Usually people consider vector bundles to have finite rank and so, as you mentioned, this would be a sum $\oplus_i E_i$ with finitely many components being non-trivial. Otherwise you would have an infinite dimensional fiber. Is this not satisfying for what you want to do? If not, maybe it would help to know some more details about your setting and your goal.

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/graded+vector+bundle
nlab tends to be a pretty good source for things like this. According to this definition, a graded vector bundle is simply a vector bundle whose fibres are graded vector spaces.